# Union and intersection of given sets (even numbers, primes, multiples of 5)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to compute the intersections and unions of the following sets ...

$A=\{x:x\in \mathbb{N}\ \text{and x is even}\}$

$B=\{x:x\in \mathbb{N}\ \text{and x is prime}\}$

$C=\{x:x\in \mathbb{N}\ \text{and x is a multiple of 5}\}$

a. $A\cap \!\,B=$ {2}

even and prime, if it's even it's divisible by 2, so 2 is the only even and prime number

b. $B\cap \!\,C=$  {5}

multiple of 5 and prime, so 5 is the only choice

c. $A\cup \!\,B=$ {all prime natural numbers and all even natural numbers}

d. $A\cap \!\,(B\cup \!\,C)=$ {all even numbers that are either prime or divisible by 5}

I am not sure about my answers for parts c and d specifically. I understand union and intersection but I am a little unsure about how to actually write out my answers.

Comment: Maybe you should add some comments to your post explaining what you are actually doing...

Comment: @russoo the answers for a and b are pretty self explanatory, but i added some comments anyways

Comment: I would probably just write what you did and provide a Venn diagaram as explanation.

Comment: Ok, that is not what I had in mind. I just thought it would be nice if you start your post with sometihng like "I am trying to compute the intersections and unions of the following sets ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer for part c is correct. There are a number of more "formal" or "mathy" ways of writing it. For example, $A\cup B=\{n:n\in\Bbb{N}, 2|n\vee n\in\Bbb{P}\}$. This means, "the set of all $n$ where $n$ is a natural number, and $2$ divides $n$ or $n$ is prime." However, using the symbol $\Bbb{P}$ to represent the prime numbers is not universally accepted. It is perfectly acceptable to use words in certain mathematical statements, so you could say
$$A\cup B=\{n\in\Bbb{N}:n\textrm{ is prime or }n\textrm{ is even}\}.$$
Your answer for part d is also correct. For this you could say
$$A\cap(B\cup C)=\{n\in\Bbb{N}:2|n\textrm{ and }(5|n \textrm{ or }n\textrm{ is prime})\}.$$
In general, a union means you combine the set conditions with an "or" and an intersection combines them with an "and". Also, if a "mathy" description is more cumbersome than a simple one, as is the case with primes, it is usually okay to use English. We know what prime numbers are; you don't need to say
$\{p\in\Bbb{N}:nq=p\wedge q\in\Bbb{N}\Longrightarrow q=1\vee q=p\}$.

Comment: for part d i would add that the condition of even and divisible by 5 implies that we're talking about all natural numbers divisible by 10.

Comment: @user3440448 You certainly could do that. I considered writing it that way, since it simplifies the set-building to "$n$ is prime or $10$ divides $n$," with two conditions instead of three. The longer way has a clearer connection to the original set, so I thought it would be better for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's all ok, but you could expand a bit on d); personally, I'd distribute the intersection to understand better what's happening:
$A\cap \!\,(B\cup \!\,C)=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)$
First part, you answered in a.: {2}
Second part: even multiples of 5, so multiples of 10.
All in all, {x:x=2 or x multiple of 10}.